# Syntax error on encoderForArrayFormat on IE

Tags: babeljs, nuxt.js

Im using Nuxt 2.4

On dev environment, I'm having this issue.

[image]

[image]

For my nuxt.config.js

```
build: {
transpile: ['vuetify/lib'],
plugins: [new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()],
loaders: {
  stylus: {
    import: ["~assets/style/variables.styl"]
  }
},

/*
** You can extend webpack config here
*/
extend(config, ctx) {

}
```

}

Comment: Search engodeforaarayformat in your node nodules to find out what library it's from

Comment: The package https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string is causing the issue. You may use the es5 version instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string-es5

Comment: Hi,

I solved it by adding proxy on axios.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding proxy on axios.

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if there was more information here about how exactly the problem was solved and not just that it was solved by adding a proxy.